# How can I filtered out a list element from html to vanish it from the table?

Tags: javascript, html, list, hidden

I want to catch the list with `title="Datenschutz"` and hide it. How could I do this?

HTML:

```
<div id="Footer">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" title="AGB">AGB</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Impressum">Impressum</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Datenschutz">Datenschutz</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Copyrightbestimmungen">Copyrightbestimmungen</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried. What tools are you hoping to use or specifically avoid?

Comment: Do you want to do this server side (i.e. php) or client side (javascript)?

Comment: what method do you prefer? you can hide it using css: a[title=Datenschutz] { display: none }. It will only hide anchor, not the whole list item tho...

Answer (score 2):

This method uses `document.querySelector` which has [decent modern browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)

```
function removeListElementWithTitle(title) {

    // Find anchor elements with specified title attribute
    var foundAnchor = document.querySelector('a[title=' + title +']');
    if (foundAnchor) {

        // Get the anchors parent and remove it from the DOM
        var li = foundAnchor.parentNode;
        li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
    }
}

removeListElementWithTitle('Datenschutz');
```

If you don't want to remove the element replace the removeChild with this to hide.

```
li.style.display = 'none';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r3WQr/

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = document.querySelectorAll('a[title=Datenschutz]');
t[0].parentNode.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: That´s great. Thanks for the minimal version.

Comment: I'd suggest using @Jason Harwig version - it's more universal, and reusable